# Check the uniform convergence of parametric integral

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence

While $0< \alpha <+ \infty$, prove if the parametric integral is uniform convergent on $\alpha$'s domain:
$$\int^{+ \infty}_{0} e^{- \alpha x} \sin \beta x dx$$
$\beta$ is nonzero constant.

Comment: You can use the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Lebesgue_lemma

Comment: For those curious, it can be shown using [Euler's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_formula) that the value of the integral is $\dfrac b{a^2+b^2}$ .

Comment: would you please give more hints?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question.  Do you mean that you're supposed to show that the integral
$I(\alpha,\beta) \to f(\alpha)$ uniformly as $\beta \to \infty$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integral is uniformly convergent for $\alpha \in[\delta,\infty)$ for each $\delta >0$.

This follows from the Weierstrass Test since

$$|e^{-\alpha x}\sin{\beta x}| \leq e^{-\delta x}$$

for $\alpha \geq \delta$ and the integral of the RHS converges:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\delta x}dx= \frac1{\delta}$$

However, it is not uniformly convergent for $\alpha \in (0,\infty)$.

To prove non-uniform convergence we can show there are sequences $\alpha_n \rightarrow 0$ and $b_n < c_n \rightarrow \infty$ such that

$$\int_{b_n}^{c_n}e^{-\alpha_n x}\sin{\beta x} dx \geq \frac1{4 \beta}.$$ Assuming WLOG $\beta > 0$, choose $0 < b < c$  such that

$$\int_{b}^{c} \sin{\beta x} dx = \frac1{\beta}\int_{\beta b}^{\beta c} \sin{x} dx \geqslant \frac{1}{2\beta}.$$

Let $b_n = 2\pi n + b$ and $c_n = 2\pi n + c$. Then

$$\int_{b_n}^{c_n}e^{-\alpha_n x}\sin{\beta x} dx \geq e^{-\alpha_n c_n}\int_{b_n}^{c_n}\sin{\beta x} dx \geq \frac1{2 \beta}e^{-\alpha_n c_n}.$$

Now let $\alpha_n$ be a sequence that converges to $0$ and satisfies

$$\alpha_n < \frac{\log(2)}{2\pi n  + c}.$$

Then

$$\int_{b_n}^{c_n}e^{-\alpha_n x}\sin{\beta x} dx \geq\frac1{2}e^{-\alpha_n c_n} > \frac1{4 \beta}.$$

Note, also, that for $\alpha = 0$, the integral diverges (oscillates).

Comment: @user154357: I assumed you were considering uniform convergence with respect to $\alpha$ rather than $\beta$